# C# How to get number of child collection items with condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given a `List<CourseSchedule>` variable,
how to get the total number of elements in all the collections `List<CourseSection>` of all courses with a given SemesterID using LINQ? Is it possible in this case?

The class structure is the following:

```
class CourseSchedule
{
   public Course Course {get;set;}
   public List<CourseSection> Sections {get;set}
}

class Course
{
   public int SemesterID {get;set};
   public string SemesterName {get;set;}
}

class CourseSection
{
   public int SectionID {get;set;}
   public string SectionType {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This seems like maybe homework? What have you tried? Please post your attempt.

Comment: @itsme86 I totally agree with you and did make attempts I assure you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope I understood what you intend. Following should help you.

```
list.Where(x=>x.Course.SemesterID==semesterId).SelectMany(x=>x.Sections).Count();
```

Or (as pointed out by juharr)

```
list.Where(x=>x.Course.SemesterID==semesterId).Sum(x=>x.Sections.Count);
```

Comment: yes thats exactly it, beautiful answer, somehow i did not come to me.

Comment: Or `.Sum(x => x.Sections.Count)`